# Calculating time difference returns null

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select everything from the post and calculate the time difference between you and when it was posted and I am using

```
SELECT FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, post.created) / 60)) 
FROM post
```

as my query to calculate it to minutes but when I execute this query some of the records return null and I do not know why this is

`2021-12-16 21:31:09` the query does not work for this date

`2021-12-18 17:01:37` but for this one it does

does anyone know a fix?

Comment: this works `SELECT FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '2021-12-16 21:31:09')) / 60);`

Comment: You I think had the `)` a bit muddled, so its just a TYPO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3d91748d585ac15c6ccc4ba28e483e95), it looks like it's failing at the `TIME_TO_SEC()` call:

```
SELECT FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, post.created) / 60)) as result,
   timediff(current_timestamp, post.created) as step1,
   TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, post.created) / 60 as step2,
   TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, post.created) / 60) as step3
FROM post
```

Results:

| result | step1 | step2 | step3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | 45:09:30 | 7515.5000 | null |
| 151 | 01:39:02 | 231.7000 | 151 |
| null | -46:20:58 | -7700.9667 | null |
| null | 838:59:59 | 139765.9833 | null |

*This is the kind of debugging step you ought to be able to take on your own :/*

However, it is reasonable to still need help after narrowing the problem as above, and with that in mind this is probably the result of a mis-placed parentheses. It seems like you're want to divide by 60 *after* the `TIME_TO_SEC()` call:

```
FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, post.created)) / 60)
```

Comment: I could find out what I was doing wrong for over an hour so really thank you.